# Duplicate Week and Date Time Values in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am running into an issue trying to convert datetime values consistently into years, weeks, and months.
I was able to figure out how to convert a particular date into a Year/Wk/Month combination, but because of the overlap in week and month numbers, I am encountering duplicate combinations which I want to account for. For example:

- 2019/ Week 31 / Aug: this is because august 1 is still part of week 31 in the calendar, but the month extracted is in August
- 2019/ Week 31 / Jul: this is because July 31 is still part of week 31 in the calendar, but the month extracted is in July
  My goal is to avoid having duplicates and wrong values extracted. Another example:
- 2019/ Week 01 / Dec: this is because december 31 is part of week 01 in the new year, and it's tied to calendar year 2019.

[image]

This is my code:

- req_df is the original dataframe
- req_total_grouped for me to group values based on a loc/filter, grouping by datecol which is a date value (ex: 2020-01-01)

```
import calendar
req_total_grouped = req_df.loc[req_df['datecol'] >= '2019-07-01'].groupby(req_df['datecol'])
req_total_df = req_total_grouped.count()
req_total_df['YEAR'] = req_total_df['datecol'].dt.year
req_total_df['WEEK'] = req_total_df['datecol'].dt.week.map("{:02}".format)
req_total_df['MONTH'] = req_total_df['datecol'].dt.month.apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])
req_total_df['YR_WK_MTH'] = req_total_df['YEAR'].astype(str) + \
                            '/ Week ' + \
                            req_total_df['WEEK'].astype(str) + \
                            ' / ' \
                            + req_total_df['MONTH']
```

My desired output:

- In cases where there are month overlaps, I would want there to be a uniform value. It doesn't matter which month I take they just need to be under the same week. (ex: 2019/ Week 31 / Aug and 2019/ Week 31 / Jul should consolidate into one single value '2019/ Week 31 / Aug' for example)
- In cases where there are year over laps (ex: 2019 / Week 01 / Dec) should be 2020 / Week 01 / Jan

Comment: Can you please provide a desired output, i.e. how do you want to manage these cases?

Comment: To add to @Marcel request. I am confused at how 2019/Week 31/August is invalid. If august 1st is still part of week 31 then the date according to that format is valid. The only edge case I can see is then last one since I'm assuming you are setting the start of a week to be Monday.

Comment: So you basically want to drop duplicates for the week number? so that there is e.g. only one entry for 'Week 31'? And you don't care which entry is dropped?

Comment: Thanks for providing the desired output. I can suggest a workaround: set your date or at least a copy of `req_total_df['datecol']` to the last day of the week (let's say Sunday if going by the European convention). i.e. If your date is 30-June-2020 (Tue), then set it (or a copy) to 05-July-2020 (Sun).

This way any entries from this week will be `2020 / Week 27 / Jul` in your `YR_WK_MTH` column.

Pseudocode:

`req_total_df['new_col'] = req_total_df['datecol'] + 7 - weekday(req_total_df['datecol'])`  Where `weekday()` is a function returning 1 for 1st day and 7 for last day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

I guess grouping the rows by 'year' and 'week' and keeping the last value of each group gives your desired result. Can you try this?

Data (same as yours?)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('01/01/2019', '12/31/2020', freq='D')})
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month.apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])
df['week'] = df['date'].dt.week.map("{:02}".format)
df['yr_wk_mth'] = df['year'].astype(str) + ' / Week ' + df['week'] + ' / ' + df['month']
```

Code:

```
print(df.groupby(['year','week'])['yr_wk_mth'].last())
```

Result:

```
                date month             yr_wk_mth
year week                                       
2019 01   2019-12-31   Dec  2019 / Week 01 / Dec
     02   2019-01-13   Jan  2019 / Week 02 / Jan
     03   2019-01-20   Jan  2019 / Week 03 / Jan
     04   2019-01-27   Jan  2019 / Week 04 / Jan
     05   2019-02-03   Feb  2019 / Week 05 / Feb
     06   2019-02-10   Feb  2019 / Week 06 / Feb
     07   2019-02-17   Feb  2019 / Week 07 / Feb
     08   2019-02-24   Feb  2019 / Week 08 / Feb
     09   2019-03-03   Mar  2019 / Week 09 / Mar
     10   2019-03-10   Mar  2019 / Week 10 / Mar
     11   2019-03-17   Mar  2019 / Week 11 / Mar
     12   2019-03-24   Mar  2019 / Week 12 / Mar
     13   2019-03-31   Mar  2019 / Week 13 / Mar
     14   2019-04-07   Apr  2019 / Week 14 / Apr
     15   2019-04-14   Apr  2019 / Week 15 / Apr
     16   2019-04-21   Apr  2019 / Week 16 / Apr
     17   2019-04-28   Apr  2019 / Week 17 / Apr
     18   2019-05-05   May  2019 / Week 18 / May
     19   2019-05-12   May  2019 / Week 19 / May
     20   2019-05-19   May  2019 / Week 20 / May
     21   2019-05-26   May  2019 / Week 21 / May
     22   2019-06-02   Jun  2019 / Week 22 / Jun
     23   2019-06-09   Jun  2019 / Week 23 / Jun
     24   2019-06-16   Jun  2019 / Week 24 / Jun
     25   2019-06-23   Jun  2019 / Week 25 / Jun
     26   2019-06-30   Jun  2019 / Week 26 / Jun
     27   2019-07-07   Jul  2019 / Week 27 / Jul
     28   2019-07-14   Jul  2019 / Week 28 / Jul
     29   2019-07-21   Jul  2019 / Week 29 / Jul
     30   2019-07-28   Jul  2019 / Week 30 / Jul
     31   2019-08-04   Aug  2019 / Week 31 / Aug
     32   2019-08-11   Aug  2019 / Week 32 / Aug
     33   2019-08-18   Aug  2019 / Week 33 / Aug
     34   2019-08-25   Aug  2019 / Week 34 / Aug
     35   2019-09-01   Sep  2019 / Week 35 / Sep
     36   2019-09-08   Sep  2019 / Week 36 / Sep
     37   2019-09-15   Sep  2019 / Week 37 / Sep
     38   2019-09-22   Sep  2019 / Week 38 / Sep
     39   2019-09-29   Sep  2019 / Week 39 / Sep
     40   2019-10-06   Oct  2019 / Week 40 / Oct
     41   2019-10-13   Oct  2019 / Week 41 / Oct
     42   2019-10-20   Oct  2019 / Week 42 / Oct
     43   2019-10-27   Oct  2019 / Week 43 / Oct
     44   2019-11-03   Nov  2019 / Week 44 / Nov
     45   2019-11-10   Nov  2019 / Week 45 / Nov
     46   2019-11-17   Nov  2019 / Week 46 / Nov
     47   2019-11-24   Nov  2019 / Week 47 / Nov
     48   2019-12-01   Dec  2019 / Week 48 / Dec
     49   2019-12-08   Dec  2019 / Week 49 / Dec
     50   2019-12-15   Dec  2019 / Week 50 / Dec
     51   2019-12-22   Dec  2019 / Week 51 / Dec
     52   2019-12-29   Dec  2019 / Week 52 / Dec
2020 01   2020-01-05   Jan  2020 / Week 01 / Jan
     02   2020-01-12   Jan  2020 / Week 02 / Jan
     03   2020-01-19   Jan  2020 / Week 03 / Jan
     04   2020-01-26   Jan  2020 / Week 04 / Jan
     05   2020-02-02   Feb  2020 / Week 05 / Feb
     06   2020-02-09   Feb  2020 / Week 06 / Feb
     07   2020-02-16   Feb  2020 / Week 07 / Feb
     08   2020-02-23   Feb  2020 / Week 08 / Feb
     09   2020-03-01   Mar  2020 / Week 09 / Mar
     10   2020-03-08   Mar  2020 / Week 10 / Mar
     11   2020-03-15   Mar  2020 / Week 11 / Mar
     12   2020-03-22   Mar  2020 / Week 12 / Mar
     13   2020-03-29   Mar  2020 / Week 13 / Mar
     14   2020-04-05   Apr  2020 / Week 14 / Apr
     15   2020-04-12   Apr  2020 / Week 15 / Apr
     16   2020-04-19   Apr  2020 / Week 16 / Apr
     17   2020-04-26   Apr  2020 / Week 17 / Apr
     18   2020-05-03   May  2020 / Week 18 / May
     19   2020-05-10   May  2020 / Week 19 / May
     20   2020-05-17   May  2020 / Week 20 / May
     21   2020-05-24   May  2020 / Week 21 / May
     22   2020-05-31   May  2020 / Week 22 / May
     23   2020-06-07   Jun  2020 / Week 23 / Jun
     24   2020-06-14   Jun  2020 / Week 24 / Jun
     25   2020-06-21   Jun  2020 / Week 25 / Jun
     26   2020-06-28   Jun  2020 / Week 26 / Jun
     27   2020-07-05   Jul  2020 / Week 27 / Jul
     28   2020-07-12   Jul  2020 / Week 28 / Jul
     29   2020-07-19   Jul  2020 / Week 29 / Jul
     30   2020-07-26   Jul  2020 / Week 30 / Jul
     31   2020-08-02   Aug  2020 / Week 31 / Aug
     32   2020-08-09   Aug  2020 / Week 32 / Aug
     33   2020-08-16   Aug  2020 / Week 33 / Aug
     34   2020-08-23   Aug  2020 / Week 34 / Aug
     35   2020-08-30   Aug  2020 / Week 35 / Aug
     36   2020-09-06   Sep  2020 / Week 36 / Sep
     37   2020-09-13   Sep  2020 / Week 37 / Sep
     38   2020-09-20   Sep  2020 / Week 38 / Sep
     39   2020-09-27   Sep  2020 / Week 39 / Sep
     40   2020-10-04   Oct  2020 / Week 40 / Oct
     41   2020-10-11   Oct  2020 / Week 41 / Oct
     42   2020-10-18   Oct  2020 / Week 42 / Oct
     43   2020-10-25   Oct  2020 / Week 43 / Oct
     44   2020-11-01   Nov  2020 / Week 44 / Nov
     45   2020-11-08   Nov  2020 / Week 45 / Nov
     46   2020-11-15   Nov  2020 / Week 46 / Nov
     47   2020-11-22   Nov  2020 / Week 47 / Nov
     48   2020-11-29   Nov  2020 / Week 48 / Nov
     49   2020-12-06   Dec  2020 / Week 49 / Dec
     50   2020-12-13   Dec  2020 / Week 50 / Dec
     51   2020-12-20   Dec  2020 / Week 51 / Dec
     52   2020-12-27   Dec  2020 / Week 52 / Dec
     53   2020-12-31   Dec  2020 / Week 53 / Dec
```